# What would be the worst case for this algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I was unsure what would be the worst case running time for this algorithm considering comparisons of values and assignments to variables would it be having max at **n-1** element in the val array and min at **n-2** element and having the array **sorted in ascending order from element 0 to n-3?**

This is the algoritm:

```
int max= -1; int min = 10000;
int [] val = {SOME_VALUES_FROM_0_TO_9999};
for (int i=0; i<val.length; i++)
 if (val[i]>max) max = val[i];
for (int i=0; i<val.length; i++)
 if (val[i]<min) min = val[i];
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that the position of the "max" and "min" elements affect the running time much (since both loops have fixed lengths).  Perhaps a few words about how you think the assignment operation is weighted in timing would help.

Comment: @hardmath i am a bit confused by what you mean would it not be the worst case if the array is sorted in ascending order and max is the last element in the array meaning there is the most possible assignments possible made to the max variable

Comment: Wherever the max element is, you will not realize what it is until you have checked every element (and similarly for the min element).

Comment: @hardmath yes but we have [0,1,2] and [1,2,0] the first one will have to assign 1 as max after first iteration then assign 2 as max after 2nd iteration meanwhile my 2nd array will only have to assign 2 as max and then since 0 < 2 only have to male 1 assignment, where as the first list will have to make 2 assignments to the variable max do you see what i mean now?

Answer (score 1):

You are right with your idea that the order of the elements in $val$ effects the total running time costs of your program. However, it has no effect on its asymptotic running time complexity in terms of Big-O analysis.

For the sake of simplicity let us introduce something what we will call time unit.

Accessing an element in an array via index $i$ takes one time unit. Doing a single comparision (like $x < y$ or $x > y$) takes one time unit. An assignment statement (like $a=b$) takes one time unit. Adding two values ($a+b$) takes one time unit.

Now, let us proceed with analyzing the provided program step by step. The first two statements take two time units as they are simple assignments. Now, in the first for-loop we do a single assignment at the very beginning (int $i=0$) which takes one time unit. At each iteration we do one comparision and accessing one value (the length of the array) $i < val.length$ which together takes two time units (of course modern compilers will optimize this, but we do not care at the moment). Then we increment $i$, which is actually the same as $i = i + 1$, thus we add two values and assign them back to $i$. Together this takes two time units. So all in all for each iteration we need four time units.

The body of our loop does a comparision by accessing the value in $val$ at index $i$ and comparing it to the value stored in $max$. Thus, for each iteration we need two time units. Now, here comes the "tricky" part. How often do we enter the if-statement? Assuming the worst case, then $val$ is ordered in ascending order, hence we enter the statement in the first loop at each iteration. Hence, we need four time units for each iteration (two for the comparision, one for the assignment of $max$ and one for accessing the $i$th element of $val$ again). And this is set regardless what values are in $val$ (sorted integers in ascending order of course).

Now, consider that our array contains $n$ values. Then, we perform our loop $n$-times. Combining the time units, which we have examined above, yields to $2+1+n(2+2+2+2)=8n+3$.

Now, the second loop. Since $val$ only contains values in the range $[0 \cdots 9999]$ and $min=10000$ and our list $val$ is ordered in ascending order, we do exactly one assignment (and one array accesss) inside the second if-statement. So, instead of performing this $n$ times (as in the first loop), we only do this a single time. Hence our second loops takes $2 + n (2+2+2)=6n+2$.

We have a total cost of $8n+3+6n+2=14n+5$. However, in terms of Big-O analysis we of course have $14n+5 \in O(n)$.

**Edit:** Notice, that having alternating values (as you have suggested) does not effect this running time. Assume that $val$ is not ascending (meaning that it does not hold that $val[i] < val[i+1]$, then the $i+1$ time the first if-statement of the first loop will not be entered (because of the first assignment). Then, the second loop could be entered at $i+1$ instead. However, this would just sum up to the same running time.